# Get calendaritem from Outlook -> there is an exception

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I get the exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll Additional information: The Url property on the ExchangeService object must be set.

on:

```
..., new PropertySet());.
```

in

```
public void GetEWS()
        {
            // Initialize values for the start and end times, and the number of appointments to retrieve.

            //$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013)
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
            const int NUM_APPTS = 5;


            // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
            CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());

            // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
            CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

            // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
            cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);

            // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe first " + NUM_APPTS + " appointments on your calendar from " + startDate.Date.ToShortDateString() +
                              " to " + endDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + " are: \n");

            foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
            {
                Console.Write("Subject: " + a.Subject.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("Start: " + a.Start.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("End: " + a.End.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you haven't set the URL for EWS to use (which is what the error is telling you) and you also haven't set the credentials to use. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn509511%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn467891(v=exchg.150).aspx

Cheers
Glen